# Parser Error Message: The file 'XXX.aspx.vb' does not exist. IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, webforms

I have an project of type Application Web - Web Forms. In the version local I haven't problems to execute the web site, but when I publish the site and set to iis server I have a error; it is next:

[image]

"The file 'XXX/XXX.aspx.vb'" does not exist. this happens on all pages except the main page

**This is code WFActividadesHSEQ.aspx**
[image]

I changed the property CodeFile to CodeBehin and get the next error:

[image]

"Could not load type 'XXXXX'"

The principal page I can view because it is configure in file web.config

[image]

[image]

**This is code wfclave.aspx**
[image]

In the iis server, I first create a folder:

[image]

later, paste the files published of application web and finally I converted the folder to Application.

I also set the properties of each .aspx and .aspx.vb file "copy to output directory"

[image]

these files are in the folder "sigmac_app"

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: How did you deploy the project? Are you publishing the project through VS?

Comment: @DingPeng Hil! I'm publishing the project through VS. I right click on the project, configure it as "Debug" and publish.

Comment: Can it run normally when debugging in VS? This error seems to be that sigmac_app was not found.

Comment: Yes, I can do it.

Comment: @DingPeng when I publish the project, I see that the .aspx.vb classes are not included; it is in visual basic

Comment: You can try to put them in the same project for publishing.